# Dynamic value assign in rspec-puppet

Tags: rspec, puppet, rspec-puppet

Is there any option to assign values for parameters dynamically in rspec-puppet?

Below is my sample rspec-puppet test case. Right now, I've hard-coded all the FQDN and hostname details.

Is it possible to assign these value dynamically?

```
let :facts do
  {
   :fqdn      => 'puppet.example.com',
   :hostname  => 'puppet',
   :ipaddress => 'xxx.yy.ee.zzz'
 }
end

it do
  should contain_host('puppet.example.com').with(
    'ensure'       => 'present',
    'host_aliases' => 'puppet',
    'ip'           => 'xxx.yy.ee.zzz'
    )
end
```

Comment: To what end specifically? Unit tests usually do rely on hard-coded input values in order to check for expected results.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, since rspec itself is ruby code itself, you can do something like this:

```
['1.1.1.1','2.2.2.2'].each do | ip_address |

  context "with an IP Address of #{ip_address}" do
    let :facts do
      {
        :fqdn      => 'puppet.example.com',
        :hostname  => 'puppet',
        :ipaddress => ip_address,
      }
    end

    it do
      is_expected.to contain_host('puppet.example.com').with(
        'ensure'       => 'present',
        'host_aliases' => 'puppet',
        'ip'           => ip_address,
        )
    end
  end
end
```

You can also do something similar with `shared_examples` and `shared_contexts`:

```
shared_examples :compile, :compile => true do
  it { should compile.with_all_deps }
end

shared_context 'redhat_facts' do |operatingsystem, operatingsystemrelease|
  let(:facts) { super().merge({
      :osfamily => "RedHat",
      :operatingsystem => operatingsystem,
      :operatingsystemrelease => operatingsystemrelease
  }) }
end
```